# Three.js detect video is ready to play on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, three.js, html5-video

I'm using a video on a sphere texture and attempting to only show the sphere once the video has loaded. On mobile I always get a black sphere when the video has loaded, and after a few seconds the video starts playing.

Is there anyway to detect if the video on the sphere is actually playing before showing it?

```
      if(!video){
        video = document.createElement( 'video' );
        video.width = 2048;
        video.height = 1024;
        //video.autoplay = true;
        video.loop = true;
        video.crossOrigin = '';
        video.preload = 'auto';
   }

// video.src = cdnPrefix + "/"+ sceneObject.video;
    video.src = cdnPrefix + "/uploads/out3_8.mp4";





    geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 60, 40 );
    var texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( video );
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

    var material   = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : texture } );
    // material.side = THREE.BackSide;

    panoVideoMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    panoVideoMesh.scale.x = -1;
    panoVideoMesh.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;

    if(!isMobile)
        panoVideoPlay();
    else
        window.addEventListener('touchstart', function videoStart() {
            panoVideoPlay();
            this.removeEventListener('touchstart', videoStart);
        });

    scene.add( panoVideoMesh );
    panoVideoMesh.visible = false;

}

 function panoVideoPlay(){
  video.load();

    video.addEventListener('canplay',function(){
        scene.remove(box);
        panoVideoMesh.visible = true;
        video.play();
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can get by
video.readyState is true or false

There are many other useful function and property  of video tag in Html 5 , you can check here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Comment: ReadyState is a number. It's 4 when it can play. I've tried using that and it's the same, black for 2-3 seconds on mobile.

Comment: from your function panoVideoPlay you should remove video.load and video.play().....
use both these function above where you put video.src ... so that video load as fast as possible even before your model is initialize

ready state 4 means  HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA - enough data available to start playing